# The DateAxisItem sometimes becomes invisible

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I checked out this version of pyqtgraph

```
git clone https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git
git checkout origin/date-axis-item
pip uninstall pyqtgraph
python setup.py install
```

I then run this program. It appears to run fine, except that my x-axes of timestamps goes in and out of view without me doing anything. Not sure if this is a bug in this program or in `DateAxisItem`. Also, the milliseconds are always a multiple of 100. So for example, I see 00:00:00:900, 00:00:01:200, but never 00:00:00:042?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May 14 21:09:44 2015

@author: idf
"""

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PySide.QtCore import QTime, QTimer
from collections import deque

t = QTime()
t.start()
data = deque(maxlen=20)

class TimeAxisItem(pg.DateAxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeAxisItem, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [QTime().addMSecs(value).toString('hh:mm:ss.zzz') for value in values]

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic time-plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)

plot = win.addPlot(title='Timed data', axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
curve = plot.plot()

def update():
    global plot, curve, data
    data.append({'x': t.elapsed(), 'y': np.random.randint(0, 100)})
    x = [item['x'] for item in data]
    y = [item['y'] for item in data]
    curve.setData(x=x, y=y)

tmr = QTimer()
tmr.timeout.connect(update)
tmr.start(800)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: You are defining your own AxisItem here. Why do you need to inherit from DateAxisItem?

Comment: Because I want to control how many decimals places show on the fractional seconds part. Otherwise it would be 6 decimal places long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what happens with your DateAxisItem. As you know it's not yet merged into the main development branch of PyQtGraph. However, for your particular application, it might be easier to start from scratch and define your own TimeAxisItem? If you start from the following code, what functionality would be missing?

```
class TimeAxisItem(AxisItem):

    def __init__(self, orientation, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(orientation, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [self.get_tick(v, spacing) for v in values]

    def get_tick(self, ts, spacing):
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
        # Here you can decide on the accuracy of the time data
        # displayed depending on the spacing.
        if spacing > 60:
            return "%02d:%02d" % (dt.hour, dt.minute)
        else:
            return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second)
```